# Get namespace of function

Tags: r, namespaces

I'm developing a package where I wish to add an edit history to an object. The package allows other packages to register functions for editing the object. I'm looking for a way to record the version of the package that registered the function that was used for the edit.

The question is: Given a function how do you get the package from where it was exported? My idea is to investigate its search path, but `search()` only reports the search path for the current environment and thus not for a function, which is what I need.

Any pointers to other approaches is greatly appreciated.

The context for getting the package is this:

```
registerFunction <- function(fun) {
  package <- getPackage(fun)  ## This is what I need
  version <- getPackageVersion(package)
  register(fun, package, version)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getAnywhere`  For example, if you're looking for the namespace for the `stringr` function `str_locate` you can do

```
getAnywhere("str_locate")$where
# [1] "package:stringr"   "namespace:stringr"
```

This will work as long as `stringr` is *"visible on the search path, registered as an S3 method or in a namespace but not exported."*

The result is a named list, and you can see what's available from `getAnywhere` with `names`

```
names(getAnywhere("str_locate"))
# [1] "name"    "objs"    "where"   "visible" "dups"
```

Comment: Do you know whether multiple finds are ordered by their position on the current search path?

Comment: I've looked through the help file and it's very helpful.  I was not correct about the search paths.  See `?getAnywhere`

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
environment(fun=someFunctionName)
```

It will return the environment of the function passed as parameter, specifying also the namespace, i.e. the package name.