# R How to check that a custom function is called within a specific function from a certain package

Tags: r, function, dplyr, callstack, rlang

I want to create a function `myfun` that can only be used inside another function, in my case `dplyr`s `mutate` or `summarise`. I further do not want to rely on `dplyr`s internals (for example `mask$...`).

I came up with a quick and dirty workaround: A function `search_calling_fn` that checks all function names in the call stack and looks for a specific pattern in the calling functions.

```
search_calling_fn <- function(pattern) {
  
  call_st <- lapply(sys.calls(), `[[`, 1)
  
  res <- any(unlist(lapply(call_st, function(x) grepl(pattern, x, perl = TRUE))))
  
  if (!res) {
    stop("`myfun()` must only be used inside dplyr::mutate or dplyr::summarise")
  } else {
    return()
  }
}
```

This works as expected as the two examples below show (`dplyr` = 1.0.0)

```
library(dplyr)

myfun <- function() {
  search_calling_fn("^mutate|^summarise")
  NULL
}

# throws as expected no error
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(myfun())


myfun2 <- function() {
  search_calling_fn("^select")
  NULL
}

# throws as expected an error
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(myfun2())
```

This approach has one loophole: `myfun` could be called from a function with a similar name which is not a `dplyr` function. I wonder how I can check from which namespace a function on my call stack is coming. `rlang` has a function `call_ns` but this will only work, if the function is explicitly called with `package::...`. Further, when using `mutate` there is `mutate_cols` an internal function and `mutate.data.frame` an S3 method on the call stack - both seem to make getting the namespace even more complicated.

On a second thought I wonder whether there is a better, more official approach to achieve the same outcome: only allow `myfun` to be called within `dplyr`s `mutate` or `summarise`.

The approach should work no matter how the function is called:

1. `mutate`
2. `dplyr::mutate`

**Additional note**

After discussing @r2evans answer, I realize that a solution should pass the following test:

```
library(dplyr)

myfun <- function() {
  search_calling_fn("^mutate|^summarise")
  NULL
}

# an example for a function masking dplyr's mutate
mutate <- function(df, x) {
  NULL
}

# should throw an error but doesn't
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(myfun())
```

So the checking function should not only look at the callstack, but also try to see which package a function on the callstack is coming from. Interestingly, RStudios debugger shows the namespace for each function on the callstack, even for internal functions. I wonder how it does this, since `environment(fun))` is only working on exported functions.

Comment: Nitpick: you're missing a close `}` at the end of function `search_calling_fn`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! I corrected it.

Comment: Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429180/how-do-you-determine-the-namespace-of-a-function) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174703/get-namespace-of-function).

Comment: Your sample `mutate` code will *never* fail, because `x` is *lazy*; since it is never used, it is never "realized", so `myfun` is never called. ... but I get your point, `getAnywhere` in my answer is a little too eager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: I'm going to "borrow" from `rlang::trace_back`, since it seems to have an elegant (and working) method for determining a full `package::function` for most of the call tree (some like `%>%` are not always fully-resolved).

(If you're trying to reduce package bloat ... while it's unlikely you'd have `dplyr` and not `purrr` *available*, if you would prefer to do as much in base as possible, I've provided `#==#` equivalent base-R calls. It's certainly feasible to try to remove some of the `rlang` calls, but again ... if you're assuming `dplyr`, then you definitely have `rlang` around, in which case this should not be a problem.)

> **EDIT (2022-02-25)**: the function below uses `:::` functions in `rlang`, which (not surprisingly) no longer exist as of today, as a clear example of why using `:::`-funcs is inherently risky. *This function no longer works.* I'm not going to attempt to fix now (no immediate need/motivation). Cheers.

```r
search_calling_pkg <- function(pkgs, funcs) {
  # <borrowed from="rlang::trace_back">
  frames <- sys.frames()
  idx <- rlang:::trace_find_bottom(NULL, frames)
  frames <- frames[idx]
  parents <- sys.parents()[idx]
  calls <- as.list(sys.calls()[idx])
  calls <- purrr::map(calls, rlang:::call_fix_car)
  #==# calls <- lapply(calls, rlang:::call_fix_car)
  calls <- rlang:::add_pipe_pointer(calls, frames)
  calls <- purrr::map2(calls, seq_along(calls), rlang:::maybe_add_namespace)
  #==# calls <- Map(rlang:::maybe_add_namespace, calls, seq_along(calls))
  # </borrowed>
  calls_chr <- vapply(calls, function(cl) as.character(cl)[1], character(1))
  ptn <- paste0("^(", paste(pkgs, collapse = "|"), ")::")
  pkgres <- any(grepl(ptn, calls_chr))
  funcres <- !missing(funcs) && any(mapply(grepl, paste0("^", funcs, "$"), list(calls_chr)))
  if (!pkgres || !funcres) {
    stop("not correct")
  } else return()
}
```

The intention is that you can look for particular packages and/or particular functions. The `funcs=` argument can be fixed strings (taken as verbatim), but since I thought you might want to match against any of the `mutate*` functions (etc), you can also make it a regex. All functions need to be full `package::funcname`, not just `funcname` (though you could certainly make it a regex :-).

```r
myfun1 <- function() {
  search_calling_pkg(pkgs = "dplyr")
  NULL
}
myfun2 <- function() {
  search_calling_pkg(funcs = c("dplyr::mutate.*", "dplyr::summarize.*"))
  NULL
}
mutate <- function(df, x) { force(x); NULL; }
```

```r
mtcars[1:2,] %>% mutate(myfun1())
# Error: not correct

mtcars[1:2,] %>% dplyr::mutate(myfun1())
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

mtcars[1:2,] %>% mutate(myfun2())
# Error: not correct

mtcars[1:2,] %>% dplyr::mutate(myfun2())
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

And performance seems to be significantly better than the first answer, though still not a "zero hit" on performance:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  a = mtcars %>%
  dplyr::mutate(),
  b = mtcars %>%
  dplyr::mutate(myfun1())
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#     a 1.5965 1.7444 1.883837 1.82955 1.91655  3.0574   100
#     b 3.4748 3.7335 4.187005 3.92580 4.18140 19.4343   100
```

---

*(This portion kept for prosperity, though note that `getAnywhere` will find `dplyr::mutate` even if the above non-dplyr `mutate` is defined and called.)*

Seeded by Rui's links, I suggest that looking for specific functions might very well miss new functions and/or otherwise-valid but differently-named functions. (I don't have a clear example.) From here, consider looking for particular packages instead of particular functions.

```r
search_calling_pkg <- function(pkgs) {
  call_st <- lapply(sys.calls(), `[[`, 1)
  res <- any(vapply(call_st, function(ca) any(pkgs %in% tryCatch(getAnywhere(as.character(ca)[1])$where, error=function(e) "")), logical(1)))
  if (!res) {
    stop("not called from packages")
  } else return()
}
myfun <- function() {
  search_calling_pkg("package:dplyr")
  NULL
}
```

Realize that this is not an inexpensive operation. I believe the majority of time spent in this is dealing with the calling tree, perhaps not something we can easily remedy.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  a = mtcars %>% mutate(),
  b = mtcars %>% mutate(myfun())
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval
#     a   1.872101   2.165801   2.531046   2.312051   2.72835   4.861202   100
#     b 546.916301 571.909551 603.528225 589.995251 612.20240 798.707300   100
```

If you believe it will be called infrequently and your function takes "a little time", then perhaps the half-second delay won't be that noticeable, but with this toy example the difference is palpable.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, in general we shouldn't check for function names and only rely on checking the origin of a function. For my `dplyr` case I came up with two alternatives (see below).

Comment: Although I like the approach, I just realized that it is not actually checking the package of the function on the call stack. It just searchs for the function name in all loaded namesspaces. So if `dplyr` is loaded, but the `mutate` function is masked by another function, calling `myfun()` inside the non-dplyr `mutate` will not throw an error.

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that it searches *"in all loaded namespaces"*. Specifically, if I do `library(dplyr)`, I can do `mutate(mtcars, myfun())` without error and `transform(mtcars, myfun())` produces an error despite `dplyr` clearly being in the search path. Similarly, `transform(mutate(mtcars), myfun())` fails, since it does not find `dplyr` in the direct call chain. What makes you think that this is just searching "loaded namespaces"?

Comment: What I wanted to say was, `search_calling_pkg` is looking at the call stack and for each function name it finds, it's looking up "where" (`getAnywhere`) it can find it, and this includes all loaded namespaces, because if you `mutate <- function(df, x) {NULL}` and then call `mutate(myfun())` while `dplyr` is attached to the search path `myfun()` will not throw an error, although you are not calling dplyr's `mutate`.

Comment: Interestingly, the debugger in RStudio will show the namespace for each function on the callstack even for internal functions. I wonder how it gets this information.  `environment(fun))` for example does only work on exported functions.

Comment: Your example `transform(mutate(mtcars), myfun())` is throwing an error, because when `myfun()` is called, `mutate()` is not on the callstack. But in my example, `myfun()` finds `mutate` on the callstack, but fails to see that it is the wrong `mutate`, because all loaded packages and namespaces are listed, which have a function called `mutate`.

Comment: That's more reason to suggest that my function is working, isn't it? Perhaps I don't understand your intent with all of this (actually, I don't understand the premise behind requiring a function be called within one of `dplyr`'s functions). It would be helpful to give clear examples where it *should* error and where it *should not* (since I think I'm confused).

Comment: I updated my question with an additional note, I hope this makes my point somewhat clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, this works great. If it is not possible to use `rlang` internals (like in a package), then the best option is probably to only check the namespace with `rlang::env_name(environment(fun = ...))` (see my updated answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Above @r2evans shows how the general question of how to check whether a function is called from within another `package::function()` can be solved.

If one does not want to rely on `rlang` internal functions a possible workaround is to use `rlang::env_name(environment(fun = ...))`, however in this case only the namespace / package of the calling function can be checked and not the function name:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

check_pkg <- function(pkg) {
  
  call_st <- sys.calls()
  
  res <- lapply(call_st, function(x) {
    
    .x <- x[[1]]
    
    tryCatch({
          rlang::env_name(environment(fun = eval(.x)))
        }, error = function(e) {
        NA
        })
    
  })
    
   if (!any(grepl(pkg, res, perl = TRUE))) {
      stop("`myfun()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs")
   }  
  
}


myfun1 <- function() {
  check_pkg("namespace:dplyr")
  NULL
}

custom_fc <- mutate

mutate <- function(df, x) { force(x); NULL; }

mtcars[1:2,] %>% mutate(myfun1())
#> Error in check_pkg("namespace:dplyr"): `myfun()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs

mtcars[1:2,] %>% dplyr::mutate(myfun1())
#>   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

mtcars[1:2,] %>% custom_fc(myfun1())
#>   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For my specific issue to check if a function is called from within `dplyr` I came up with an efficient alternative using a call to `across()` as a test whether `myfun()` is called from within `dplyr`. Unlike `mask$...` etc. `across()` is an exported `dplyr` function.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

check_calling_fn <- function() {
  tryCatch({
    dplyr::across()
  }, error = function(e) {
    rlang::abort("`myfun()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs")
  })
}
  

myfun <- function() {
  check_calling_fn()
  NULL
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
a = mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate(myfun()),
b = mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate()
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#>     a 2.580255 2.800734 3.783082 3.105146 3.754433 21.043388   100
#>     b 1.317511 1.393168 1.713831 1.494754 1.763758  5.645019   100

myfun()
#> Error: `myfun()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>