# Exclude R files for R folder with .Rbuildignore

Tags: r, build, devtools

There are some files containing work under progress that I'd like to exclude from the entire build process (checking, installing, even documenting if possible), but not loading (`devtools::load_all()`).

I always name them `dev-{feature}.R` so I was about to use a wildcard, but it happened that I was not even able to exclude a single file from the build.

For debugging, I created an R file as "R/dev-myfeature.R" containing only the line `stop("TEST")`. I then ran `usethis::use_build_ignore("R/dev-myfeature.R")`, which added `^R/dev-myfeature\.R$` in the `.Rbuildignore` file.

Whether I run `devtools::load_all(".")`, `devtools::check()` or even `devtools::document()`, I get the `TEST` error, so `.Rbuildignore` was ignored. Since it works fine with all other files, I guess it has no power inside the `R` folder.

Is there any way around this limitation?

Otherwise, what would be a good workflow for work-in-progress files that should not be part of the build yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `.Rbuildignore` file is useful for bundling of your package, and that's about it. If you want certain functionality in `R/*.R` files but only on your console when testing, then you may consider structuring the test files with a wrapping `if` expression.

For example, I'll the existence and true-ness of a variable named `MYDEV` to declare that I want to load the contents of the file.

```r
if (exists("MYDEV") && MYDEV) {
  stop("TEST")
}
```

In a default environment (`MYDEV` not defined), `load_all`, `check`, and `document` do not see the error. The use of `exists(...)` helps ensure that this will not error (`object not found`) in a different R instance, either on your computer or elsewhere.

If you set `MYDEV <- TRUE`, then all the `devtools` functions will see the `stop` and error accordingly. I believe there is no (reasonable) way to get the code sourced in `load_all` and *not* with `document`.

One problem you have with *not* erring with `devtools::document` is that it calls `devtools::load_all` internally, as such simple tests do not work. One could adapt a function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62747050/3358272, with:

```r
search_calling_pkg <- function(pkgs, funcs) {
  # <borrowed from="rlang::trace_back">
  frames <- sys.frames()
  idx <- rlang:::trace_find_bottom(NULL, frames)
  frames <- frames[idx]
  parents <- sys.parents()[idx]
  calls <- as.list(sys.calls()[idx])
  calls <- purrr::map(calls, rlang:::call_fix_car)
  #==# calls <- lapply(calls, rlang:::call_fix_car)
  calls <- rlang:::add_pipe_pointer(calls, frames)
  calls <- purrr::map2(calls, seq_along(calls), rlang:::maybe_add_namespace)
  #==# calls <- Map(rlang:::maybe_add_namespace, calls, seq_along(calls))
  # </borrowed>
  calls_chr <- vapply(calls, function(cl) as.character(cl)[1], character(1))
  ptn <- paste0("^(", paste(pkgs, collapse = "|"), ")::")
  pkgres <- any(grepl(ptn, calls_chr))
  funcres <- !missing(funcs) && length(calls_chr) &&
    any(mapply(grepl, paste0("(^|::)", funcs, "$"), list(calls_chr)))
  return(pkgres && funcres)
}
```

This function returns true if any of the package/function pairs are found, and this combination will "see" (error on) `stop("TEST")` with `devtools::load_all` but not with `devtools::document`:

```r
if (search_calling_pkg("pkgload", "load_all") &&
      !search_calling_pkg("devtools", "document")) {
  stop("TEST")
}
```

Yes, this means you need `search_calling_pkg` somewhere in your environment, whether part of this package or not. Recall that if the `.Rbuildignore` file includes `R/dev-myfeature.R`, then package bundles and all down-stream users will never see this code. If you wanted to be even more defensive, you could use

```r
if (exists("search_calling_pkg") &&
      search_calling_pkg("pkgload", "load_all") &&
      !search_calling_pkg("devtools", "document")) {
  stop("TEST")
}
```